# Why console.log(super) in React Component constructor throw an Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to console the `super` in my `InheritComponent` `constructor` method.
But in chrome console, it throw an Error. Why?

```js
class BaseComponent extends React.Component{

    static defaultProps = {
        title: 'Learn React By Examples'
    }

    constructor(props) {
        console.log(props);
        super(props);
    }

    setTitle(title) {
        document.title = title || this.props.title;
        return document.title;
    }
}

class InheritComponent extends BaseComponent{
  
    state = {
      title: ''
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        //here throw an Error. Why? I want to console.log `super`
        console.log(super);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const title = this.setTitle('组件继承')
        this.setState({title});
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <p>I inherit BaseComponent</p>
            <p>current title is {this.state.title}</p>
            
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <InheritComponent />,
  document.body
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Above is my demo code.

Comment: i think you cant add anything before calling super, can you remove your console.log statement and try once?

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja remove the console.log statement will work. But I want to console the `super`. And, my console.log statement is after the `super(props)` statement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reason is simple: `super` is a keyword, not a function nor any variable. You cannot log `super` the same as you cannot log `var` or `new` keywords.

If you want to log the constructor of your parent, you can try:

```
console.log(super.constructor);
```

In fact, `super()` is just shorthand for `super.constructor()`.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Answer (score 3):

`super` is a *keyword*, you can't use it like a variable. The only allowed ways to use super are outlined [in the MDN documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super):

> super([arguments]); // calls the parent constructor.
>
> super.functionOnParent([arguments]);

If you want to print the parent class, use
`console.log(super.constructor)` instead.